# Keep only progress bar and controls on an embedded YouTube video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, embed

I have looked for a way to embed a YouTube video as an audio player for a few hours now but I have had no luck. I found mainly 3 options:
1. Make the height of the iframe 25px but I really hate the way that looks.
2. Do it with play and pause buttons, but this way I don't have a progress bar.
3. I read somewhere that you can hide the video only but keep the controls with css but I couldn't manage to pull this off.

Can someone tell me a way to do it?

Edit: I have a possible solution but I have a problem with it. The code is as it follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      iframe{
        height:0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="playeroptions.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio id="player2" preload="none" controls>
      <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{id}}" type="video/x-youtube">
    </audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my playeroption.js file I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('audio').mediaelementplayer();
});
```

In my site I cannot press any of the buttons in the audio player. How can I fix this? 
P.S I get the following error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/player/9XvXF1LrWgA/playeroptions.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Comment: "Make the height of the iframe 25px but I really hate the way that looks" What do you mean by "looks"? It sounds like only logical way to do this, so what exactly went wrong at the end? There is no way to make this in "official" way since YT does not support it, simply because it is video service and not music service (talking about standard YT and not YT music). Player supposed to play ads, and You are blocking them by hidden video stream.

Comment: It literally still shows the video, just scaled so that the height is 25px, so it is not what I am looking for. As far as I am aware what I am trying to do does not block the ads, and even if it does I am not doing it for a public website but for a school project. Therefore I am not looking for an 'official' way to do this. I am looking for a way that will still get me a good grade no matter legal or not because I won't be uploading the site. I know for a fact that doing this is possible because I already have made play and pause buttons of my own so the progress bar should be possible too.

Answer (score 1):

In comments You said that after making iframe very small, video is still visible. It is because video will always scale down/up to it's player size. 
Workaround is to make player very high. YT player will keep aspect ratio of video, so thanks to this we will end up with black bars and bottom and top. Then absolute it inside parent div, hide what's outside this and now we have just controls with black background.

**CSS:**

```
.player {
  width: 500px;
  height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.player iframe {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  border: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="player">
   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F4jYWOqHPEA?autoplay=1"></iframe>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8h71453t

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got another solution but I have a problem with it. Can you help me? I will edit the post posting the code.